# How to init 'MySocket' object with standard socket object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write my own socket class for server-client talking with RSA and AES encryption, and for server side I need to overload accept() function to return not (socket, address) pair, but (MySocket, address). So that's why I need MySocket class to be initializable with another socket.

This is simplified version of my code:

```
import socket as sock

class MySocket(sock.socket):
  def __init__(self, socket_obj = None):
    if socket_obj == None:
      sock.socket.__init__(self, family = sock.AF_INET, type = sock.SOCK_STREAM)
    else:
      assert(socket_obj.family == sock.AF_INET and socket_obj.type == sock.SOCK_STREAM)
      self = socket_obj

    self.key = 'value'

my_socket = MySocket() # works fine

print('First worked')

my_socket = MySocket(socket_obj = sock.socket()) # falls with error

print('Second also worked')
```

And after executing this code, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyoverflow.py", line 19, in <module>
    my_socket = MySocket(socket_obj = sock.socket()) # falls with error
  File "./pyoverflow.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.key = 'value'
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'key'
```

As I understand, the problem is in the #9 string `self = socket_obj`, but googling the error didn't give anything.

Comment: This code doesn’t make any sense. Assigning a new value to `self` just rebinds the local variable `self` to another object for the rest of this function. So now, you’re calling `self.key = value` on that other object, which fails. But if it didn’t fail, you still wouldn’t have done anything to the `MySocket` you’re supposed to be initializing, but instead to the other object you rebound `self` to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MySocket` is a subclass of `socket`, then a `MySocket` instance is a `socket` instance; it can't become a different `socket` instance, nor can you change another `socket` instance into a `MySocket` if it wasn't one already.<sup>1</sup>

Just assigning `self = socket_obj` doesn't do anything useful. `self` is just a local variable inside the `__init__` method. So, for the rest of the body of that method, when you do something to `self`, you're doing it to `socket_obj` instead of to your actual self. Assigning to its `key` attribute fails, as you saw. But, even if it didn't fail, all you would have done would be to modify `socket_obj`, while leaving yourself basically uninitialized.

There are two possible things that *do* make sense here, however.

---

First, instead of *being* a `socket`, your `MySocket` can *own* a `socket`, and provide the same interface as the `socket` type by delegating calls to its owned `socket`. Then, you can easily choose whether to own a newly-created socket, or one that was passed in. Something like this:

```
class MySocket:
    def __init__(self, socket_obj = None):
        if socket_obj is None:
            socket_obj = socket.socket(self, family = sock.AF_INET, type = sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket_obj = socket_obj
        self.key = 'value'
    def accept(self):
        addr, s = self._socket_obj.accept()
        return addr, MySocket(s)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            raise AttributeError(name)
        return getattr(self._socket_obj, name)
```

Writing explicit delegators (whether manually, or by looping over `inspect.getmembers(socket.socket)` and creating them programmatically) is probably a better design here than `__getattr__`, but this gets the idea across.

---

The other option is to to do effectively what [`ssl.SSLSocket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket) does.

Socket objects are basically just a thin wrapper around a file descriptor. You can call [`detach`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.detach) on a socket to steal its fd, and then you can pass that fd into the [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) initializer:

```
class MySocket(sock.socket):
    def __init__(self, socket_obj=None):
        if socket_obj is None:
            super().__init__(family=sock.AF_INET, type=sock.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            super().__init__(fileno=socket_obj.detach())
        self.key = 'value'
    def accept(self):
        addr, s = super().accept()
        return addr, MySocket(s)
```

What `SSLSocket` actually does is more complicated (although it's not *that* complicated, and it may be worth reading [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ssl.py#L781)).

But also, notice that its interface is different. Stealing another socket's fd is kind of a strange thing to do in a constructor call, so instead, `SSLSocket(socket_obj)` will raise a `TypeError`, and you're instead required to use a [`wrap_socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket) function. This is probably a less confusing design.

However, if you don't need the extra complexity of having different Context objects that all wrap sockets differently, you might just want a `@classmethod` alternate constructor method, instead of an external factory function.

---

<sub>1. Actually, in Python, you *can* sometimes change the type of a live object, by setting its `__class__` attribute. But this is almost always a bad idea, and wanting to do so is usually a sign that your design has gone very wrong somewhere.</sub>